# Form with AppScript redirect issue (XMLHttpRequest cannot load)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a very basic HTML `<form>` that in the action calls a Google Apps Script URL as the following: `https://script.google.com/macros/s/..../exec`. The App Script writes the content to a Google Spreadsheet. I'd like to redirect the user back to a specific page after it's executed, which I did with jQuery, but I get this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load  https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwg0ASXLu-2awVG_F02o5S1u1pUyrYNHaAQvxzrObFj-47vFE8/exec.
>       No 'Access-Control-Allow-  Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
>       Origin 'https://gtech-pubu.googlegoro.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Below is the entire form and jQuery. Anyone advise what I'm missing?

```js
< script type = 'text/javascript' >
  $("#courses").submit(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var $form = $(this),
      url = $form.attr('action');

    var posting = $.post(url, {
      name: $('#name').val(),
      product: $('#product').val(),
      clearness: $('#clearness').val(),
      rated: $('#rated').val(),
      helpful: $('#helpful').val()
    });

    posting.done(function(data) {
      alert('success');
    });
  }); < /script>
```

```html
<form action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwg0ASXLu-2awVG_F02o5S1u1pUyrYNHaAQvxzrObFj-47vFE8/exec" method="post" id="courses">
  <h4>Ad Exchange Sell-Side Fundamentals Content Survey</h4>

  <fieldset>
    <legend><span class="number">1</span> Module Info</legend>
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="TEST Sell-Side Fundamentals">
    <input type="hidden" name="product" value="TEST">
    <label>Select which module you wish to rate:</label>
    <select id="courses" name="clearness">

      <option value="extremely_clear">5: Extremely clear</option>
      <option value="moderately_clear">4: Moderately clear</option>
      <option value="clear_nor_unclear">3: Neither clear, nor unclear</option>
      <option value="moderately_unclear">2: Moderately unclear</option>
      <option value="extremely_unclear">1: Extremely unclear</option>
    </select>

    <label>Please rate the clarity of the content:</label>
    <select id="courses" name="rated">
      <option value="module1">Module 1</option>
      <option value="module2">Module 2</option>
      <option value="module3">Module 3</option>
      <option value="module4">Module 4</option>
      <option value="module5">Module 5</option>
      <option value="module6">Module 6</option>
      <option value="module7">Module 7</option>
      <option value="mobule8" selected>Module 8</option>
      <option value="module9">Module 9</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend><span class="number">2</span> Additional Info</legend>
    <label>Was this module helpful?</label>
    <select name="helpful" id="courses">

      <option value="yes">Yes</option>
      <option value="no">No</option>

    </select>
  </fieldset>
  <input type="submit" value="Apply" />
</form>
</div>
```

Is it in the Apps Script I need to configure to allow for the cross domain?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you must use JSONP to call the script from within an XMLHTTPRequest...

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content#serving_jsonp_in_web_pages

Try passing in JSONP as the last param to $.post

```
var posting = $.post( url, {
    name: $('#name').val(), 
    product: $('#product').val(), 
    clearness: $('#clearness').val(),
    rated: $('#rated').val(),
    helpful: $('#helpful').val() 
}, 'jsonp' );
```

Also, I don't know what your script looks like but you may have to add the MIME type...

.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT)

like in the example from the documentation...

```
return ContentService.createTextOutput(
    request.parameters.prefix + '(' + JSON.stringify(result) + ')')
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
```

Note: Also, just in case you missed it in the docs...

*Warning: Be very careful when using this JSONP technique in your scripts. Because it's possible for anyone to embed the script tag in their web page, you can be tricked into executing the script when you visit a malicious website, which can then capture the data returned. Best practice is to ensure that JSONP scripts are read-only and only return non-sensitive information.*